# ionic 4 LoadingController does not dismiss after API return

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-http-interceptors

I am using a http intercepter to add a loadingController to all API calls like this

```
 intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = "my-token-string-from-server";

    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: token
        }
      });
    }

    if (!request.headers.has("Content-Type")) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        }
      });
    }

    request = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set("Accept", "application/json")
    });
    this.presentLoading();
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log("event--->>>", event);
          //this.hideLoader();
        }
        this.hideLoader();
        return event;
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        this.hideLoader();
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
```

in the same ts file I have the loading controller functions like this

```
 async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: "Loading, Please Wait..."
      // duration: 5000
    });
    await loading.present();

    const { role, data } = await loading.onDidDismiss();

    console.log("Loading dismissed!");
  }

  hideLoader() {
    this.loadingController.dismiss();
  }
```

However, when I make an API call, I get the event `event--->>>` in the console but the loadingController is not dismissed.

P.S. If I add the `duration` to the loadingController, sometimes the loadingController is dismissed several seconds before the api returns data.

Comment: You can try calling `.dismiss()` on the actual loader `const loading` instead of the controller. Also, `.dismiss()` should return a promise, does that resolve or reject?

Comment: how do you mean @Thomas ? can you show me a code?

Comment: Something like `this.loading = await this.loadingController....` and in `hideLoader()`: `this.loading.dismiss()`. If that doesn't work log what `dismiss()` returns.